# Printing document through code running on server but using default print queue on end user's machine

Tags: javascript, java, printing

My requirement is to print a document silently. I have one web application which runs on Tomcat on server. When an end user inputs some fields in web form and submits, then code running on server generates some pdf file and send to print queue. But here no printer queue is installed on server. Requirement is to get default print queue name from end user machine and print document to that print queue and sets user name as owner name of that print job.

I am using Java Print Services (JPS) framework to print the document.

I am able to print document when code is running on my local machine in eclipse or local tomcat but when I deploy it on server, it does not print document.

Comment: `Requirement is to get default print queue name from end user machine and print document to that print queue` - your server has zero chance of adding something to my print queue without my express permission to do so ... i.e., you cant do that

Comment: Yes, you are right. So my next question is there any way to achieve this requirement in different way? User document should be printed silently (by server only) on user's default print queue (with some print attribute set) only so that user can go to RICHO printer and login to his print queue and print it.

Comment: well, there's no possible way your server can "silently" print on MY computer - so, you may need rethink what you want to achieve

Comment: Can we use Activex Object on browser to get user's default print queue details. I found some code using ActiveX in java script which gets default print queue details from user's machine register.

Comment: OK, so this is some closed environment thing ... you could do it using a browser web extension (that will cover a lot more people, since chrome/firefox/and other non-microsoft browsers can install web extensions) ... another way is with a download with a mime-type of your own making, triggering a program of your own making to do what ye will with the data that is sent

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda, Even if we ask Print Queue name from user as an input, our purpose will be solved. Next challenge is to set user name explicitly in print job so that only that user can be authorized by RICHO printer and get their print. I am able to issue print command but printing job is bydefault taking my user id even if another user is explicitly set as an owner of the print command.

Comment: So basically requirement is to issue print job from server having another user as an owner of print job so that he can only get his print. I am not sure whether I am putting requirements in a clear way.